# How to clear Javascript from IE8 cache?

Tags: javascript, caching, internet-explorer-8

I normally do web development with Chrome and sometimes FireFox.
I'm now trying to fix a problem that occurs on IE8.

After updating a Javascript file for a web page, I've tried doing the following things to be able to load the changed file:

F5
CTL-F5 [Many times]
Developer Tools > Cache > Alwasys Refresh from Server
Tools > Internet Options > Browsing History > Settings > Every Time I visit the site

But it's not picking it the changes.
I can see the file is changed within Chrome

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/866619/how-to-force-ie-to-reload-javascript

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Ctrl-R` is short cut for clearing cache.

The always refresh from server is reset when you close the browser

Comment: Another concern with the "only when you close the browser" is you may have to close all open IE windows, not just that one instance.

Comment: Well, Ctrl-R didn't do it.  But your suggestion about closing the browser seems to have done it.  I closed Developer Tools and then shut down the browser and then restarted IE8.  I'm anxious to go back to Chrome...

Answer (score 2):

Give this a shot, it's kind of a similar problem.

[How to force IE to reload javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866619/how-to-force-ie-to-reload-javascript)

I would think something else is going on if you are able to see it in Chrome.  Close out IE completely after clearing everything and start a new instance.